# Memory efficiency with NSTableView and SQLite data

Tags: macos, cocoa, sqlite, nstableview

I'm probably over-thinking this problem so if there's suggestions and a cleaner head then i'm all ears.

The problem is I want to store a growing amount of data in an SQLite database and be able to display it in an `NSTableView` in my application where users will interact with it, I am concerned about just pre-loading the table into an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects and traversing just simply implementing something like

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tView objectValueForColumn:(NSTableColumn *)column row:(NSInteger)row {
  return [[myData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:column.identifier];
}
```

There are two possibilities - one, the data set could get large (>500,000 records) and two, the data might end up in a database server on a local network where records could be inserted by a companion app which then messages all other running instances to do a `reloadData` on the table - lets concern ourselves less about the second for now though.  The default view would be to see all records and then a filter would reduce them.

So, should I be worrying about how much data would be in the NSArray/NSDictionary because OSX's memory management would just shuffle it to a disk based cache etc so all I need to do is update the database when a record changes and call reloadData?

Or should I consider the idea of making the NSArray very lightweight and just hold unique ID's to the records in the database and fetch each as required - as the SQLite is local to the app this would be expensive on lookup but not debilitating I would imagine.  This method would satisfy both the view all and view filtered results scenario anyway.

At this point i'm not using custom cells so i'll leave the OS to worry about reuse queues etc and cross that bridge later.

Should I have the model of my application cache the current row so that each column's value is 
 just a lookup from a data object?

I have considered core data but the upscaling requirements potentially later may prove a hinderance and I am at breaking point with Apple's documentation style.

Comment: You need to cache the data locally, either in an NSArray or SQLite.  But you can "lazy load" the data.  For one app with potentially thousands of table entries I built a "sparse array" mechanism that allowed a large DB to be demand-loaded and still back up a table view.  A memory warning would flush the array on an LRU basis.

Comment: Is there a good example for this, i've had trouble with lazy loading in the past on iOS, could never figure out what was on screen and what was not.

Comment: It requires thought.  But you can always ask the table view what range of entries are currently displayed.  Or, like I did, just use true LRU and you will hardly ever discard an entry that's needed by the display.  (Note that to do lazy loading you need some indication in the table cell that an entry is being loaded, to provide the user with some "feedback".)

Comment: I've had to temporarily implement what I noted above, when `objectValueForColumn:` is called, the routine uses a model which manages an array which holds the IDs for the placement in the table.  I can even apply filtering this way.  Each row then works out if the data for that row is loaded and caches it for the remainder of the calls for each column.  I tested it with about 5000 entries and it didn't seem too sluggish as the SQLite db is local to the machine the app runs on. If I go network multiuser later i'll have to re-address this.